# Elements of $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{Aut}(G))$ acting as an identity on $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$

Tags: group-theory

Let an element $f$ of  $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{Aut}(G))$ acts as an identity on $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ then does it act as an identity on $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$?

I have taken an element of $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ say $h$ then $h$ is equal to $g\cdot{k}$ where $g$ is in $\operatorname{Aut}(G)$ and $k$ in $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$. Next what?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895408/elements-of-operatornameaut-operatornameautg-acting-as-an-identity-on

Answer (score 4):

No. Take $G$ abelian of order more than 3. Then $\operatorname{Inn}(G)=1$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(\operatorname{Aut}(G))\neq 1$.

Comment: Now take G non abelian & simple

Comment: @user152715 You made no restrictions on the group in your question. Not even finiteness. If you meant specific kinds of groups, you should edit your question appropriately.